# index 41 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 41

Tags: python, ubuntu, index-error

I've got errorcode following traceback.
Can I change data[z,y,x] to data[0,0,0]?
Then, it worked.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/suhui/Downloads/dry.py", line 1194, in <module>
    harvest, affinity = getpoints(grid, coord(w), distance = 1.0) # angstroms
  File "/home/suhui/Downloads/dry.py", line 739, in getpoints
    harvesting.append( data[z,y,x] )
IndexError: index 41 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 41
```

Here is my code.

```
pt_scan = int( round(float(distance)/(spacing)) )
if pt_scan == 0: pt_scan = 1 # at least one point around
if DEBUG: print "Grid range: %2.2f [ +/- %d points : %2.2f ]" % (distance,pt_scan, pt_scan*spacing), 
best = 999

if (coords[0] < max[0]) and (coords[0] > min[0]):
    if (coords[1] < max[1]) and (coords[1] > min[1]):
        if (coords[2] < max[2]) and (coords[2] > min[2]):
            z_pt = int(round((coords[2] - min[2])/spacing))
            y_pt = int(round((coords[1] - min[1])/spacing))
            x_pt = int(round((coords[0] - min[0])/spacing))

            for x_ofs in range(-pt_scan, pt_scan+1): 
                x = x_pt + x_ofs
                if x < 0 :
                    harvesting.append(0)
                    break
                for y_ofs in range(-pt_scan, pt_scan+1): 
                    y = y_pt + y_ofs
                    if y < 0 :
                        harvesting.append(0)
                        break
                    for z_ofs in range(-pt_scan, pt_scan+1): 
                        z = z_pt + z_ofs
                        if z < 0 :
                            harvesting.append(0)
                            break
                        harvesting.append( data[z,y,x] )
                        if data[z,y,x] < best:
                            best = data[z,y,x]
        if DEBUG: print " %d pts [ best: %2.2f ]" % (len(harvesting), best),
        return harvesting, best
return False
```

Please help me.... Seriously i cannot understand...
Can you find my error?

Comment: At a guess, if your array size is `41` then you're being told that index `41` is out of bounds because the array is 0-indexed. That is to say that the first element in the array is actually index 0, thus the 41st element of the array is index 40.

Comment: Thank you. To solve this, what should I have to change..?

Comment: It's hard to say with so many nested for loops. Try printing different values that get incremented to see which comes out as your `IndexError`

Comment: @Seong, have a read through [here](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to get some ideas for debugging.

Comment: The assumption that "pt_scan = 1" means "one point around" could be wrong. If you process `range(-pt_scan, pt_scan+1)` with pt_scan == 1 you will have the values -1, 0, 1, 2. That's four values, not one. If you mean one point in either direction, that's wrong too, because it is one in the negative direction and two in the positive.